# Error in carouselPicker intent activity

Tags: android

I want to add intent function on different position of my carouselpicker but it is saying that intent activity is not defined in the manifest but i have already declared it in manifest 
pls help

## carouselpicker intent activity

```
carouselPicker1.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if(position == 0){
                    startActivity(new    Intent(getActivity(), website_designing.class));
                }
                else if(position == 1){
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), digital_marketing.class));
                }
                //position of the selected item
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

## manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="in.goodiebag.carouselpicker"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/responsive"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="WebTechniQ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Registration"
            android:label="Query Form">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: *`Error in carouselPicker intent activity`* What error? you need to  share that error with question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
website_designing
```

and

```
digital_marketing
```

should be defined in manifest as well as yours `Registration` and `Splash`

Just a remark. `website_designing` and `digital_marketing` do not match to Java naming conventions.